# TextFormField become non-editable after the set text on its controller

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried several ways to solve the problem. But still, I got some issues. The code below shows the exact implementation I did for my application. The idea is to make the textfieldform accept the user input and also set the data value which loads from the database. But, after I use the method like =>  `itemPriceController.text = [databaseloadedvalue]`, the textfield becomes static where the user cannot edit/change the content set on the controller. **The below code is for demo purposes only**

```
class AddItemFromImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String company, productName;
  final bool isImageInput;
  const AddItemFromImage(
      {Key? key,
      required this.company,
      required this.productName,
      required this.isImageInput})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddItemFromImage> createState() => _AddItemFromImageState();
}

class _AddItemFromImageState extends State<AddItemFromImage> {
  TextEditingController itemNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController itemPriceController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController itemDiscountController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController totalItemCountController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    itemNameController.dispose();
    itemPriceController.dispose();
    itemDiscountController.dispose();
    totalItemCountController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    itemNameController.text = "Viyasan Dev Muthusamy";
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: !widget.isImageInput
          ? AppBar(
              title: Text(
                "SampleCode Test",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            )
          : null,
      body: Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 40.0),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            child: Text(
              AppStringHolder.lblMsgImgItem,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 40.0),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              onTap: () {},
              controller: itemNameController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              onChanged: (value) => onChangedItemName(value),
              decoration: _commonInputStyle(Colors.blueGrey, Colors.blueGrey,
                  AppStringHolder.lblItemName, false),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 60.0),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include how and where you've declared `itemPriceController`?

Comment: It would be great if you included some code

Comment: sure will edit the post accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your init state ;

---

example:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    itemNameController.text = "Viyasan Dev Muthusamy";

    super.initState();
  }
```

Your Problem will be solved